# How to install RA3 uprising on ubuntu without origin?

Tags: 20.04, wine, files, games, playonlinux

Can anyone help me? I got a pc with ubuntu 20.04 LTS and i already got wine and playonlinux (and not-working-origin on playonlinux) and i got RA3 uprising game files from my windows pc with origin copied, and i want to install it but when i run RA3launcher.exe, it says origin is not installed. Can anyone fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give it a try and upload this question to a forum that has to do with Ra3. They might help you better, as not many ppl that use ubuntu (and are surfing this forum) might play Ra3.

Comment: Thanks! ill try it there, but i dont think it'll work, because it has to do with the file not locating a specific program.

Comment: I see. Try everywhere. Facebook, random gaming forums, even in-game's multiplayer, ask the other players.

Comment: I got an idea, but i dont know if it will work: mayby boot up origin.exe from wine, and then login at my account with RA3.